# Is there any grammar correcting software in TeXmaker?

Tags: texmaker, punctuation, spelling, grammar

I am interested in a grammar correcting software in TeXmaker if there is one around like in Microsoft word: it's possible to correct grammar : commas placing, redundant expression, non-formulated expressions ,punctuation marks etc...

thanks

Comment: As an approximation while no solution is implemented yet, these steps: https://danious.wordpress.com/2013/10/07/grammar-latex/ have been automated here: https://github.com/HiveMinds-EU/Productivity-setup yielding cli view of LanguageTool for your `.tex` files. However, it is not integrated with TexMaker. I expect the integration with notepad++ seems more readable than the CLI, yet that is not yet automated and also still isn't integration with TexMaker. Disclaimer, I'm involved in the mentioned git.

Answer (score 1):

You can use LanguageTool in TeXstudio. If you really need it, consider to switch.

Comment: i've found LanguageTool but i don't know if it possible to use it with texMaker ? However, i think i'll use Microsoft Word for now ... But since you are talking about texStudio can you give me an overview on how to configure LanguageTool with it , thanks

Comment: It's explained here: http://wiki.languagetool.org/checking-la-tex-with-languagetool#toc4