# Automatic grammar checker for LaTeX documents?

Tags: spelling, grammar

I'm currently writing a thesis. I'm using the Texmaker editor with the built-in dictionary for grammar correction (British English). Unfortunately, I'm short of time, so I don't have time to read everything again.

Texmaker only marks spelling mistakes. Is there a tool which can detect wrong or missing commas and perhaps weird sentences?

Comment: hm, I read my thesis again and again and correct any discovered glitches in it so long that all was as it had to be. In generally this show candidate attitude to thesis as well his knowledge background.  This should not be replaced with some artificial intelligence, isn't it?

Comment: i think the tool you want is a grammar checker, so that would be better stated in the title.

Comment: @Zarko I have written > 100 pages and still not finished...

Comment: The tool you are after is a human. Nothing currently is faster or more reliable. If you want to give me a link I could look through 5 or a bit pages.

Comment: Duplicate of [Is there any grammar correcting software in TeXmaker?](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/314419/is-there-any-grammar-correcting-software-in-texmaker) . If you really need grammar checker, switch to TeXstudio - [Installing Language Tool in TexStudio](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/155148/installing-language-tool-in-texstudio)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You should read everything again, several times. That said, here are two suggestions:

- Have a grammatically literate friend read your thesis.
- A clumsy (relatively) quick way to get some (possibly useful) help:

> Save the compiled pdf as a word file, and run word's grammar checker.

Most of the problems found will be spurious, but a few may be real and you can fix those.

If you compile your thesis (temporarily) without ligatures and without hyphenation then there will be fewer "errors" to ignore in the doc file.

**Edit** in response to OP's comment.

- In my acrobat pdf viewer I can choose Word on the save-as menu, or
  Google https://www.google.com/#q=pdf2word+online+converter
- Google https://www.google.com/#q=latex+suppress+ligatures
- Google https://www.google.com/#q=latex+suppress+hyphenation

Comment: How can I export it to word file? How can I compile it without ligatures and hyphenation?